# React context api lose auth data when react router dom push page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an context where i save the user data, and i have another component when verify the context user is null, if the context user is null my component should redirect the user to the login page, if not should render the component. My routers is inside my Authprovider, but still losing the user data when reload the router. I found another posts with the same issue, and the instruction is to keep the routers inside the useauthprovider, but doesn't work with my app.

My code

```
function App() {
  let header = window.location.pathname === '/login' || '/cadastro' ? <Header /> : null;
  let footer = window.location.pathname === '/login' || '/cadastro' ? <Footer /> : null;
  return (
    <UseAuthProvider> // My use AuthProvider
      <Router>
        <div className='app-container' >
          <Switch>
            <Cart>
              <Header />
              <NavbarMenu />
              <div className='app-body'>
                <UseCampanhaProvider>
                  <PublicRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
                  <PrivateRoute exact path='/cupom/:campaignId' component={CupomScreen} />
                  <PrivateRoute exact path='/carrinho' component={CartScreen} />
                </UseCampanhaProvider>
                <PublicRoute exact path='/login' restricted={true} component={Login} />
                <PublicRoute path='/cadastro' restricted={true} component={Cadastro} />
              </div>
              <AuthModal />
              {footer}
            </Cart>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router >
    </UseAuthProvider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

My component where i verify the user context

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const { user } = useAuth();
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            !user ?
                <Redirect to='/login' />
                :
                <Component {...props} />
        )} />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

My context where i load the user

```
const UseAuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        verifyUser(); //here i call the function when verify the localstorage
    }, [])
    const verifyUser = async () => {
        let tokenHeader = authHeader(); 
        if (tokenHeader) {
            await Api.post('/cliente/index', {}, {
                headers: {
                    ...tokenHeader
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                setUser(response.data.cliente)
            })
        }
    }
    const handleModal = () => {
        setOpen((state) => !state)
    }
    
    const Logout = async () => {
        localStorage.clear('acessToken-bolao')
        setUser(null)
    }
    return (
        <useAuthContext.Provider value={{ Auth, verifyUser, user, Register, Logout, open, handleModal }}>
            {children}
        </useAuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I tried to debug my application and when i redirect my user to another router, before the component render my user return undefined, and after my component is rendered the context load the user data.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your entire application is unmounting and remounting.
In this case the state will be lost as it is not simply a re-render.

By what mechanism are you navigating to the new page?
If I remember React-Router correctly you need to use 
If you try navigating the url itself with window.location or href then you are reloading the entire page (not using the router in the SPA)

If routed correctly I would expect that only data inside the Switch would be re-loaded.

Comment: i using the history.push of the react router dom

Comment: Where are you navigating to? I think having exact on '/cupom/:campaignId' may cause you issues but I cannot see the obvious reason for a full stack remount.

You could prove this is happening by changing your verify mount effect to
    useEffect(() => {
        verifyUser();
        return () => console.log("unmounted");
    }, [])